# Which function Is similar SDL_SetColorKey() in SFML?

Tags: c++, graphics, sdl, sfml

Which function Is similar `SDL_SetColorKey()` in **SFML**?

Comment: `createMaskFromColor (color, alpha)` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the same as `SDL_SetColorKey()` you'll have to load your image into an `sf::Image` and, then as Simon G. already pointed out, use [`createMaskFromColor`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.1/classsf_1_1Image.php#a22f13f8c242a6b38eb73cc176b37ae34) to "create a transparency mask from a specified color-key". Afterwards you'll need to pass the `sf::Image` to your `sf::Texture` to be able to draw it.

If you have to do this for every image, I highly recommend to create image files with a transparent color (Portable Network Graphics recommended). Having to mask things at run time, is essentially just a legacy thing and wasted resources - unless you're doing more "dynamic"/complex things with the masking.